# Camel exec returns always null String from shell script

Tags: java, apache-camel, wicket

I have this code snippet for executing a script shell from a java Tomcat web development using wicket.

```java
public class CallingScript  extends RouteBuilder {
    String result;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:exec")
                .to("exec:ls?args=/home/foo/")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        ExecResult execresult = exchange.getIn().getBody(ExecResult.class);
                        result = execesult.toString();
                    }
                });
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

and I use it in the Onclick method in Wicket 7.0.0, no error message has been generated but always a null string is returned by the exec route.

```java
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    CallingScript call = new CallingScript();
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(call);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        camelContext.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        camelContext.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String res = call.getResult();
    getSession().info("directory contents " + res + " !");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just starting camel context is not sufficient to trigger a route. If you want to manually trigger a route, you can use [camelContext.startRoute()](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#startRoute(org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition)) method.

By the way, IMHO, It is a best practice to start one camel context for per application.